# Not accepting arraylist values in passing request method body in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi in the below i have list of arrays named as cct and intensity.Iam trying converting all the integers into single arraylist and the am sending the arraylist to the server as a request body.

Now am trying to passing arraylist as a parameter to requestbody it was showing error.

can any one please help me how to pass as a paramets

```
public void getCCTAndIntensityValues (String schedulerType){

            int cct1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT1.getProgress()));
            int cct2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT2.getProgress()));
            int cct3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT3.getProgress()));
            int cct4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT4.getProgress()));
            int cct5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT5.getProgress()));
            int cct6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT6.getProgress()));
            int cct7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT7.getProgress()));
            int cct8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT8.getProgress()));
            int cct9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT9.getProgress()));
            int cct10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT10.getProgress()));
            int cct11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT11.getProgress()));
            int cct12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mCCT12.getProgress()));


            int intensity1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty1.getProgress()));
            int intensity2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty2.getProgress()));
            int intensity3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty3.getProgress()));
            int intensity4 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty4.getProgress()));
            int intensity5 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty5.getProgress()));
            int intensity6 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty6.getProgress()));
            int intensity7 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty7.getProgress()));
            int intensity8 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty8.getProgress()));
            int intensity9 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty9.getProgress()));
            int intensity10 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty10.getProgress()));
            int intensity11 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty11.getProgress()));
            int intensity12 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mIntenisty12.getProgress()));

            ArrayList<Integer> number =new ArrayList<>();
            number.add(intensity1);
            number.add(intensity2);
            number.add(intensity3);
            number.add(intensity4);
            number.add(intensity5);
            number.add(intensity6);
            number.add(intensity7);
            number.add(intensity8);
            number.add(intensity9);
            number.add(intensity10);
            number.add(intensity11);
            number.add(intensity12);

            ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues =new ArrayList<>();
            cctvalues.add(cct1);
            cctvalues.add(cct2);
            cctvalues.add(cct3);
            cctvalues.add(cct4);
            cctvalues.add(cct5);
            cctvalues.add(cct6);
            cctvalues.add(cct7);
            cctvalues.add(cct8);
            cctvalues.add(cct9);
            cctvalues.add(cct10);
            cctvalues.add(cct11);
            cctvalues.add(cct12);
              //  cct = "[" + cct1 + " " + cct2 + " " + cct3 + " " + cct4 + " " + cct5 + " " + cct6 + " " + cct7 + " " + cct8 + " " + cct9 + " " + cct10 + " " + cct11 + " " + cct12 + "]";
              //  intensity = "[" + intensity1 + " " + intensity2 + " " + intensity3 + " " + intensity4 + " " + intensity5 + " " + intensity6 + " " + intensity7 + " " + intensity8 + " " + intensity9 + " " + intensity10 + " " + intensity11 + " " + intensity12 +"]";

            RequestAsyntask mRequestAsyntask = new RequestAsyntask(mContext);

            try {
                RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder().add("light_id", lightid).add("intensity", cctvalues.add(cct1)).add("cct",cctvalues ).build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL + schedulerType).post(requestBody).build();

                mRequestAsyntask.runDataRetriver(request, false);
                Log.i(TAG, "Sending---" + BASE_URL + schedulerType + "\n" + "light_id:" + lightid + "\n" + "intensity:" + intensity + "\n" + "cct:" + cct);

                mRequestAsyntask.setResponseListener(new ResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(String response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Response:" + response);

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your request for API calling, You need to convert your `ArrayList` into the `JSONArray` like below:-

```
try {


    ArrayList<Integer> number =new ArrayList<>();
    number.add(intensity1);
    number.add(intensity2);
    number.add(intensity3);
    number.add(intensity4);
    number.add(intensity5);
    number.add(intensity6);
    number.add(intensity7);
    number.add(intensity8);
    number.add(intensity9);
    number.add(intensity10);
    number.add(intensity11);
    number.add(intensity12);

    JSONArray numberJson = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < number.size(); i++) {

        numberJson.put(i, number.get(i));

    }

    ArrayList<Integer> cctvalues = new ArrayList<>();
    cctvalues.add(cct1);
    cctvalues.add(cct2);
    cctvalues.add(cct3);
    cctvalues.add(cct4);
    cctvalues.add(cct5);
    cctvalues.add(cct6);
    cctvalues.add(cct7);
    cctvalues.add(cct8);
    cctvalues.add(cct9);
    cctvalues.add(cct10);
    cctvalues.add(cct11);
    cctvalues.add(cct12);


    JSONArray cctJsonArray = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < cctvalues.size(); i++) {

        cctJsonArray.put(i, cctvalues.get(i));

    }
    RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder() 
    .add("light_id", lightid)
    .add("intensity", cctJsonArray.toString()). 
    .add("cct",numberJson.toString() ).build();

        /**
         * DO YOUR STUFF 
         */


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ravindra Kushwaha is right, you can put the value as String only. 
Please see the method's signature:

```
//Add new key-value pair in FormEncodingBuilder 
add(String name, String value)
```

So, you need to pass your arrayList as string, so choose wisely and add values in that manner only.

Ref.: [FormEncodingBuilder](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/FormEncodingBuilder.html)